# How do I flip an animation pose without having my character walk backwards?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have been making a walking animation. It went pretty well up to this point where I'm halfway done:

https://gyazo.com/118b8e402ea4f2aa2d89e217e1be474b

I watched a tutorial where he copied his animation and ctrl+shift+V'ed it to get the other half. I tried to do the same, but although it's close, it's not exactly what I wanted:

https://gyazo.com/89c10c29c4e68e2edb23f1bb187d0b74

The only problem is that the two halves are walking in opposite directions now. So my question is: What are my options? Do I have to manually make the poses for the other half, or can I somehow make it work with what I have here? Thank you!

Edit with link to file:

[image]

Edit 2: I ended up manually creating the second half of my animation. Below you can see the result. My question now is if I could have achieved this without having to manually animating the 2nd half?

[image: The animation I want]

Comment: Welcome @Jesper. I suggest you upload the file for analysis: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @LeoNas Thanks. I have uploaded the file.

Comment: Hi, please don't link images/screenshots from external sources, but instead use the question editor to load images: they will be permanent and embedded in your post, making easier for others to understand your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You want him to walk obliquely but it's not the right way to do it as all mirror will stay in the X or Z axis, you must create your walk cycle in *Pose* mode orthogonally to the grid THEN switch to *Object* mode and rotate it 45°.

You must keep in mind that, when you mirror a pose, it will be RELATIVE TO THE LOCAL AXIS OF THE OBJECT, so if you rotate your armature 45° in Pose mode instead of Object mode, the armature is 45° rotated but the local axis is still orthogonal to the grid and will act this way for whatever mirror you'll do. If you want to rotate the Local axis you need to do it in Object mode.

If you have secondary animations, like the head rotating, you can either do it after the rotation in Object mode OR do a second animation, the head rotation, and use the NLA to add it to the walk.

I would redo it from scratch: Close the action in the *Action Editor* (*X* button), in Pose mode select all the bones and reset the pose with <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>, in *Object* mode select your armature and rotate it 90° on the *Z* axis so that you can see its right profile in *Front Ortho* view, then back in *Pose* mode and begin with the first pose of your walk cycle.

Also, your foot is strangely set, in *Edit* mode I would delete the constraint, parent (*Keep Offset* mode) with the legIK controllers and also in *Properties* > *Bone* > *Relations*, enable *Inherit Rotation*.

If you want your character to walk sideways you have to rotate your character in *Object* mode, not in *Pose* mode

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try what you have suggested. I am a little confused by the last part though. You want me to delete the Copy Rotation constraint on my foot, parent the foot with legIK and disable inherit rotation on legIK, correct? Also, can you explain how I "parent (Keep Offset mode) with the legIK" ?

Comment: Also, I might have done something wrong, but after doing what you described I am now facing the exact same problem where the two halves are walking in opposite directions after shift+ctrl.V'ing.

Comment: sorry I meant enable inherit rotation   ;)

Comment: no you should fix your problem if you strictly follow the steps, I will check again. Update: ok so I checked and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you send me the updated file? Maybe I can see what I've done wrong

Comment: Or if it wouldn't be of too much trouble and the steps don't take long for you to do, maybe you can make a short video/gif that shows the steps.

Comment: I reset the pose, rotated it 90 degrees on the Z axis in Object mode so I had its right profile in Front Ortho view, then went into Pose mode and created the first half of my walk cycle and that's where I'm stuck: https://gyazo.com/4b0ff201698c7ca4592f56fcad54aa94

Comment: I've uploaded a picture of the different steps

Comment: Yeah that works, but I don't see how it solves my problem. I need it to walk sideways while looking straight forward. If I for example rotate the hips to face right, they will be rotated to face left when I ctrl+shift+V which makes it walk in the opposite direction. Sorry if that was not clear in the post.

Comment: if you want your character to walk sideways you have to rotate him in Object mode, not in Pose mode

Comment: But I can't rotate parts individually in Object Mode, so I don't see how that would work. Anyway, I ended up manually creating the poses for the second half of my animation. I edited my post to show the result. I guess what I really would like to know is if I could have achieved that without manually creating the poses for the 2nd half?

Comment: why do you want to rotate parts individually? Create a walk in Pose mode, ORTHOGONAL to an axis of your grid, for example your character go towards the X direction. When you have finished, come back to the Object mode, then rotate your character towards the direction you want, whatever this is, for example 45° on the Z axis. Why do you need to do that? Because when you mirror the pose in Pose mode, it will use an axis orthogonal to the grid! - Well, technically, to your Local axis, that's what you have to keep in mind!

Comment: I need to rotate parts individually because, for example, as you can see in the gif I posted, I want the character to walk sideways with the body slightly rotated to that side while the head is looking straight ahead. I need them to not be rotated the same amount to achieve this. It sounds like mirroring is not possible for achieving what I want and the way I did it is the only way.

Comment: Reformulation of what I want to say, I hope it's clearer: You must keep in mind that, when you mirror a pose, it will be RELATIVE TO THE LOCAL AXIS OF THE OBJECT, so if you rotate your armature 45° in Pose mode instead of Object mode, the armature is 45° rotated but the local axis is still orthogonal to the grid and will act this way for whatever mirror you'll do. If you want to rotate the Local axis you need to do it in Object mode. So for your animation, create the walk cycle, then rotate the character in Oblect mode, and only then make some additional animations like the head...

Comment: So just to be clear: All parts that I want to be rotated in the animation (like the head, actually everything in my case) is something that I have to do manually for the whole animation after creating the walk cycle. It's not something I can just mirror. Correct?

If yes, then great, because that is basically what I ended up doing - I was just hoping there was an easier way. If not, then sorry, I guess I just don't get it.  Maybe I'm just too dumb. Anyway, thanks for trying to explain it.

Comment: yes, create the animation orthogonally to your Local axis, then in Object mode rotate your character, and only then make your secondary animations like head. BUT if you have a lot of secondary animations the best is to use the NLA editor window, that will allow you to keep the walk intact and a second, third, fourth animations, etc... you can stack several animation tracks: for example on the first one the basic walk, and over this one the animation of the head. Watch some tutorials about the NLA editor.